# Why django authenticate always return none

Tags: django, django-forms

i have a few questions

1. why Authenticate() always return none but when i tried using Exists() its return the user?
2. Can we just using Exists() for user login?

Im using django 1.11.7 and class based views

this is my views.py

```
class ShopLoginView(FormView):
    template_name = 'shop/login.html'
    form_class = LoginForm
    success_url = '/shop/'
```

this is my forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):

    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField()

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(LoginForm, self).clean()
        email  = cleaned_data.get("email")
        password  = cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            print(user)
        else:
            print(user)
            raise forms.ValidationError("Wrong Email or Password")
```

this is when i use the Exists() method

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):

    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField()

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(LoginForm, self).clean()
        email  = cleaned_data.get("email")
        password  = cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = User.objects.filter(email=email, password=password)

        if user.exists():
            print(user)
        else:
            print(user)
            raise forms.ValidationError("Wrong Email or Password")
```

any ideas to what might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

You've somehow stored the password in plain text. You should *not* be able to use `filter` or `exists` to find a user by username and password; the plain text password should not match.

`authenticate` will always hash the password it is passed and compare it with the existing hashed version in the db. Since your saved password is not hashed, it does not match.

You didn't show how you created the user, but you must always use `create_user` or set the password with `set_password`.

Answer (score -1):

you can just check authentication like this as authenticate decode the hash password and then match:-

```
 user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
 if user and user.is_active:   
          print(user)
```